# Is there a way I can get my player to spawn above the ground and stay there while being able to move

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey soz im a bit new to coding, in this platformer game I made the player keeps spawning below to ground, but I can see its head. It moves like normal which is good because the code I used before
made the player bobble above and beneath the ground.

here is the code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool onPlatform = false;
        foreach (PictureBox platform in platform)
        {
            if (IsColliding(player, platform))
            {
                onPlatform = true;
                player.Top = platform.Top - player.Height;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (IsColliding(player, ground))
        {
            onPlatform = true;
        }

        if (!onPlatform)
        {
            player.Top += speed;

            bool foundPlatform = false;
            foreach (PictureBox platform in platform)
            {
                if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(platform.Bounds))
                {
                    onPlatform = true;
                    foundPlatform = true;
                    player.Top = platform.Top - player.Height;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!foundPlatform)
            {
                onPlatform = false;
            }

            if (!onPlatform)
            {
                if (player.Bottom < this.ClientSize.Height - ground.Image.Height)
                {
                    player.Top += speed;
                    if (num >= 3)
                    {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    num++;
                    player.Image = walkAnimation[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    jumpCount = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                jumpCount = 0;
            }
        }

        if (!onPlatform)
        {
            player.Top += speed;

            bool foundPlatform = false;
            foreach (PictureBox platform in platform)
            {
                if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(platform.Bounds))
                {
                    onPlatform = true;
                    foundPlatform = true;
                    player.Top = platform.Top - player.Height;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!foundPlatform)
            {
                onPlatform = false;
            }

            if (!onPlatform)
            {
                if (player.Bottom < this.ClientSize.Height - ground.Image.Height)
                {
                    player.Top += speed;
                    if (num >= 3)
                    {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    num++;
                    player.Image = walkAnimation[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    jumpCount = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                jumpCount = 0;
            }
        }

        if (movedown && player.Bottom >= ground.Top && player.Bottom < this.ClientSize.Height)
        {
            player.Top = ground.Top - player.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            if (moveleft && player.Left > 0)
            {
                player.Left -= speed;
                if (num >= 2)
                {
                    num = 0;
                }
                num++;
                player.Image = walkAnimation2[num];
            }
            if (movedown && player.Bottom > 0)
            {
                player.Top += speed;
                if (num >= 3)
                {
                    num = 0;
                }
                num++;
                player.Image = walkAnimation[num];
            }
            if (moveright && player.Right < this.ClientSize.Width)
            {
                player.Left += speed;
                if (num >= 3)
                {
                    num = 0;
                }
                num++;
                player.Image = walkAnimation3[num];
            }

            if (isJumping && onPlatform)
            {
                if (verticalVelocity == 0)
                {
                    verticalVelocity = jumpSpeed;
                }
                player.Top -= verticalVelocity;
                verticalVelocity--;
                jumpCount++;
                if (jumpCount > jumpHeight * 2)
                {
                    isJumping = false;
                    jumpCount = 0;
                    verticalVelocity = 0;
                }
                else if (jumpCount > jumpHeight && onPlatform)
                {
                    isJumping = false;
                    jumpCount = 0;
                    verticalVelocity = 0;
                }
                else if (player.Bottom >= this.ClientSize.Height - ground.Image.Height)
                {
                    isJumping = false;
                    jumpCount = 0;
                    verticalVelocity = 0;
                }
                player.Image = walkAnimation4[num % 4];
            }
        }

        if (movedown && player.Bottom >= ground.Top && player.Bottom < this.ClientSize.Height)
        {
            player.Top = ground.Top - player.Height - 1;
        }
    }










    private void platform1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void platform2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ground_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private int num;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyUp += Form1_KeyUp;
        KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
    }




    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            moveleft = false;
            player.Image = walkAnimation[0];
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            moveright = false;
            player.Image = walkAnimation[0];
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            movedown = false;
            player.Image = walkAnimation[0];
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            isJumping = true;
            player.Image = walkAnimation[0];
        }
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            moveleft = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            moveright = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }

    }


    private void pad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private bool IsColliding(PictureBox pb1, PictureBox pb2)
    {
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(pb1.Location, pb1.Size);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(pb2.Location, pb2.Size);
        return rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2);
    }

}
```

}

```
            //player.Top = ground.Top - player.Height;
```

everytime the timer ticked it checked whether or not the player was colliding with the ground, if it was it teleported the player to the top of the ground. The player would start to collide with the ground and would be teleported up just to collide again, making the bobble

Comment: the code is in winforms

Comment: You probably want to separate the code into methods, to make it easier to read and maintain. It looks like you doubled the collision code. By accident? Might there be a plus/minus error when you are determining the new player location after Collison? Or might the player height be incorrect?